How much should I make ADHD 8 year old work to solve puzzles before I give hints?
My 8 year old, soon to be 9, niece loves lateral thinking puzzles and has been asking me for them regularly.  For context these are puzzles where you are given a strange situation and have to figure out what is happening with only yes or no questions.  They usually involve at least one 'lateral leap', ie realizing something unintuitive or an intentional trick hidden within the puzzle to solve them as well.
She's liked them ever since she solved her first one years ago - she got lots of hints but considering how young she was then it was pretty impressive she solved it at all so I praised her for it. Just yesterday she was practically shouting in glee that the kid in my puzzle was blind when she finally figured out why the child 'never saw his father again'; but she only got there once I started getting pretty helpful and volunteering extra details I'm not suppose to give to her questions designed to get her to realize her presumption that something bad happened to the father couldn't be right.
She is pretty good at solving the 'lateral leap', for her age at least.  Her biggest problem is that she wants to leap straight to guessing the answer.  while more complicated puzzles usually require starting with more general questions designed to narrow down the situation and get more detail before one knows enough to have a realistic chance of solving the puzzle.  I've been trying to tell her this and encourage her to start asking more of these generalized questions rather then trying to jump to the solution, with limited success.
Right now my biggest problem is she gets frustrated and starts asking for hints quickly.  If she can't solve it all in one go she wants a hint to point her in the right direction rather then working towards methodically asking questions to expand her understanding of the situation.  I like how the puzzles engage her problem solving skills, but feel she would get more out of them if I pushed her to work more to try and solve her confusion herself before she get's hints; but I don't want to make the puzzles so frustrating for her that she stops wanting to do them.
I also have the problem that I can't provide puzzles fast enough to satisfy her.  I'd dare say I'm pretty decent at coming up with these sorts of puzzles, but she goes through them so quickly, thanks partially to all the hints she demands, that I just can't come up with puzzles fast enough to keep up with her demands and I'm starting to struggle with finding new puzzles she hasn't heard yet online to supplement the ones I create at this point.  If we don't slow her down somehow I'm going to reach a point where I simply have no puzzles to offer her soon.
My biggest problem is that when I delay hints she starts begging for them more and more or just declare she gives up and want's the answer rather then continuing to try to solve the puzzle.  I've tried to explain the steps to get better at solving the puzzles, even giving 'hints' that were basically to ask more questions about a specific subject since that would lead to more information.  But my niece still tends to demand instant gratification and doesn't seem to want to try if she can't guess the answer all at once.
I should probably mention she is ADHD and by the time we get to puzzles her medication has usually worn off and she's hyperactive, which no doubt contributes to her inpatients.
So how much work should she have to put in to before she get's help, and how do I keep her engaged and interested when I delay giving her hints?

Those kind of riddles are called 'Black Stories' where I live. Usually - but not always - they have some dark (more or less child unfriendly) aspect in the story, hence the name. However, I can see that there exist child friendly versions, too (e.g. "Red Stories"). I'm just commenting this so you could find inspirations for more riddles ;)

Is she on medication for her ADHD?

yes, but by the time I get one on one time with her to do these puzzles it's usually worn off soo... ;)

I slightly disagree with /u/Cdn_Dev; at 9 years old the important thing is not solving independently, it's engaging with the child. Each hint is engagement between your niece and you; if you don't want to engage, you leave them the puzzle when you head off to work for them to work on it all day alone, and then they can discuss it with you later.
A couple of things struck me from your question:

My biggest problem is that when I delay hints she starts begging for them more and more or just declare she gives up and want's the answer rather then continuing to try to solve the puzzle.

Yeah, this is a sign that you shouldn't delay hints. If not giving hints kills the game, then you should be giving hints.

I'm not suppose to give to her

Suppose? This isn't a job interview, the rules are made up, by you. You can give whatever hints you like!
Crucially, the whole point of hints is to manage the difficulty level of puzzles in a way that makes all the puzzles achievable. Your niece is nine, as you say, that's quite young for these puzzles; the hints are literally what's making the game accessible to her. There will be time in the future for her to challenge herself, but a nine year old with ADHD has quite enough challenges already.

I feel she would get more out of them if I pushed her to work more to try and solve her confusion herself before she get's hints

Then explain this to her; but at the end of the day, maybe she wouldn't. Maybe spending time trying to focus on too wide a possibility space would actually use up her limited willpower that she has to spend on not getting upset about 9-year-old life, rather than building up that resource.
On the other hand, there's nothing wrong with putting an obstacle in her path. Make her earn the hint. Don't have her sit there and be frustrated, she has to do something for another hint. Get you a cup of tea, do a question on her maths homework, put a book back on the bookshelf. Anything easy but valuable. That makes the hint valuable, and keeps them engaged rather than frustrated.
Alternatively, get a piece of paper and simply tally up the number of hints; make the hints easily accessible, but it's more impressive if she uses less hints. Never criticise her for using hints, but praise her when she uses less. "Wow, you only needed three hints, well done!"

I also have the problem that I can't provide puzzles fast enough to satisfy her. I'd dare say I'm pretty decent at coming up with these sorts of puzzles, but she goes through them so quickly, thanks partially to all the hints she demands, that I just can't come up with puzzles fast enough to keep up with her demands and I'm starting to struggle with finding new puzzles she hasn't heard yet online to supplement the ones I create at this point. If we don't slow her down somehow I'm going to reach a point where I simply have no puzzles to offer her soon

Your game seems a lot like 20 questions, so one way is to simplify it; you choose a thing or character (e.g. Scooby Doo) and she asks yes/no questions to work out who it is.
You can also branch out to different types of riddles or puzzles. Try watching shows like Taskmaster or Game Changer for inspiration.
There's also classic games like Monkey Island on the computer that you can play together. I really like the game Cryptmaster for riddles.
Finally, I can wholeheartedly recommend the Kosmos EXIT game series. Great puzzle games to play.
You seem like a lovely uncle/aunt, if your niece is enjoying playing with you, celebrate that, don't try and change it just because you think you're "supposed to".

Just to be clear, I'm not suggesting that he run off and leave her alone, I'm suggesting that he find a way to engage as little as he can, and leave most of the problem solving for her. He definitely should engage if this is what she needs, but if he wants to encourage her problem solving skills he should find a way to minimize this as much as possible. That doesn't mean being a jerk, it just means doing as little as she's comfortable with. That addresses the limit that the question asks about.

"I'm suggesting that he find a way to engage as little as he can, and leave most of the problem solving for her." Yeah, my point is just that I'm not sure that's where the value is in the exercise. The question was 'should'; and I thought your answer was really good, but at answering for a 'low should'

I'm thinking I may not have worded my answer carefully enough, it's a tricky concept to communicate. It really is possible to have the best of both worlds, engagement and encouragement. With my boys, I always make sure they're having fun, but I also do what I can to maximize the amount they're doing. Once they stop having fun, that's how to know I need to increase my support.

Humans tend to lean towards the easiest route, thats just efficiency. In this case the hints make it easier, without any concequences.
I would suggest you propose a new rule:

Lets make this a bit more challenging! I offer the same riddles, but now with a maximum of three hints, use them wisely! If you run out of hints and still don't know I win! Lets see if I can beat you!

Of course the '3' could also be '5', whatever you think is right. You could also ask her how many she things she needs and respond to that.
When the hints are used up you could

Say "Ah too bad! I win!" and tell the answer anyway. Its about the interaction, not winning anyway. The fact that she knows the answer but lost anyway might make her more careful
Say "Ah too bad! I win! Now you will never know". That might be super frustrating the first (few) time(s), but that does up the ante. Next round hints might be used more wisely.
Add some stakes beforehand, eg the loser needs to make the other a victory drink. She might now get the answer anyway, but needs to pay the stake too.


My only concern is that once the hints are used up, the efficient thing to do is exactly what's mentioned in the question: Quit and demand the answer.

@deworde: I've added a part to my answer.

As a general rule you want to help with everything they do as little as possible. 'As possible' here basically means that you increase your support when they start getting upset or aren't having fun.
In your child's case the exact method of doing this isn't clear cut, but in general you want to find a way to do as little as possible without actually upsetting your child. Causing them to be frustrated is what you want if it means that they figure out the problem and gain confidence. Just don't let the frustration turn into emotional harm.
But given your specific situation it sounds like she's become completely reliant on your help and shuts down without it, so I'd maybe question the utility of doing the puzzles at all with so much assistance. It might be a good opportunity to explain to her that she'll get more out of the puzzles by doing most of the work herself. And if she absolutely refuses and gets upset due to minimal help, it might be time to pick a different challenge or activity that she's more self motivated to tackle.
Just to be clear, I'm not suggesting that you run off and leave her alone, I'm suggesting that you find a way to engage as little as you can, and leave most of the problem solving for her. You definitely should engage if this is what she needs, but if you want to encourage her problem solving skills you should find a way to minimize this if you can. That doesn't mean being a jerk, it just means doing as little as she's comfortable with. That addresses the limit you're talking about - how much should I make her work. You should make her work as much as you can without her getting upset.
I'm taking this strategy from Jane Nelsen's Positive Discipline, where she mentions 'never do for a child what they can do themselves'. Basically what this means here is that the more she does, and the less you do, the more she's going to learn. But the integral aspect of this approach is that you don't damage your relationship with the child.
